# How to figure out/debug what loaded a javascript into browser

Tags: javascript, debugging, browser

I integrated a shop application, which loads in Chrome, but not in Firefox. Now I try to find out the difference. It loads dynamically several javascript files through dynamically created  tags.
I found out one is loaded in Chrome only. But which javascript file out of 5 huge minified files loaded it?

I'm trying to understand how those scripts work, but it takes time... Look for function names...

Currently you can see it here: http://angular.lonskaya.com/recordings

loads in Chrome, but not in Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this one myself, so sharing. May be it'll help somebody.

In Firefox and Chrome in the Network Tab of the development tools you can select the javascript file for which you want to know how it was requested.

In Firefox you navigate to "Call list" tab then: it looks quite similar to call list for functions and you can navigate to the actual line from here.

In Chrome you have the "initiator" column and you see the call list when you hover over the column with you mouse.